# Força da tipagem na linguagem Lua

Tags: característica-linguagem, tipagem, lua

Lua possui tipagem dinâmica, mas afinal, é fortemente tipada ou fracamente tipada? Cada fonte que consulto possui uma informação diferente, o que me deixou na dúvida.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

Não há fonte confiável sobre o que é a força da tipagem. Já vi várias definições e muitas pessoas consideram que não tem relevância. Há quem diga, e isso parece ser claramente errado, que tipagem dinâmica e fraca são a mesma coisa, bem como tipagem estática e forte.

O entendimento que vejo mais por aí, e as palavras podem não ser as mais adequadas, é que a tipagem fraca permite que um valor de um tipo, e todo valor tem tipo, possa ser interpretado como se fosse de outro tipo. Isso pode ser só o uso de forma diferente ou pode ser por uma conversão implícita (esta última há controvérsias).

A tipagem forte determina que o valor só é usado pelo tipo que ele foi concebido e não se relaciona com outros tipos de forma implícita (controversamente).

É possível que seja considerado forte quando a linguagem só aceita reinterpretações/conversões que tenham significado óbvio e correto, e fraco quando permite qualquer situação de uso do valor de forma diferente ao que deveria, ou seja, ele tenta fazer a operação dentro de algum critério, mesmo que o resultado não seja adequado.

Não sei se podemos dizer que todas linguagens sejam 100% forte ou fraca na tipagem.

O meu entendimento é que Lua tem tipagem essencialmente forte. Tem algumas exceções. Os operadores de adição e concatenação fazem conversões implícitas.

Concordo que a concatenação transforme tudo em *string*, muitas linguagens consideram *string* como um tipo universal que qualquer valor pode ser convertido sem chance de erro (embora isso não seja uma verdade absoluta, tem tipos que não produzem um texto significativo).

Já que o operador de adição não pode ser confundido com concatenação acho justo que outros tipos sejam convertidos para números quando o usa, mas vejo algum problema porque nem sempre a operação será bem sucedida. Mas isto é debatível, uma divisão por zero também pode gerar erro, um *overflow* também, e é melhor que seja gerado erro em vez de produzir um resultado errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Conceptual.md).